# Difference of averages of columns in 2 tables in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I have split a table into 2 based on the average value of a column and now I want to calculate the difference in the average of the other columns in the new tables.

e.g. (simplified example, my data has 5 columns)

```
t1 =      'id', 'price', 'size'

           1 ,  10.0,     3    

          ...,   ...,    ...   

           10,   6.50,    8       

t2 =      'id', 'price', 'size'

           11 ,  12.12,   3    

          ...,   ...,    ...  

           20,   3.50,    5    '

diff_table  =  'diff_price'               ,'diff_size'

               t1.avg_price - t2.avg_price, t1.avg_size - t2.avg_size
```

Comment: Not very clear but as I understand it you want the new values to be a view or table
This can be done with a select query but you will have to do an additional query to insert them into a database or create a function that can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, pretty simple as:

```sql
SELECT
    avg(t1.price) - avg(t2.price) AS diff_price,
    avg(t1.size) - avg(t2.size) AS diff_size
FROM t1, t2;
```

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eXuc1bUyxAHhWo2Yu91GMt/0

If you need that data to be put into a new table, just do the following )with explicit column typescale):

```sql
CREATE TABLE diff_table AS
SELECT
    (avg(t1.price) - avg(t2.price))::decimal(10,2) AS diff_price,
    (avg(t1.size) - avg(t2.size))::decimal(10,2) AS diff_size
FROM t1, t2;
```

...result:

```sql
                  Table "public.diff_table"
   Column   |     Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------
 diff_price | numeric(10,2) |           |          | 
 diff_size  | numeric(10,2) |           |          |
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I resolved my own problem.

```
CREATE TABLE diff AS
SELECT AVG(bathroomcnt) AS avg_bathroomcnt,
       AVG(bedroomcnt) AS avg_bedroomcnt,
       AVG(calculatedfinishedsquarefeet) AS avg_calculatedfinishedsqrft,
       AVG(garagecarcnt) AS avg_garagecarcnt,
       AVG(lotsizesquarefeet) AS avg_lotsizesqft,
       AVG(roomcnt) AS avg_roomcnt
FROM higher_values;

CREATE TABLE diff2 AS
SELECT AVG(bathroomcnt) AS avg_bathroomcnt,
       AVG(bedroomcnt) AS avg_bedroomcnt,
       AVG(calculatedfinishedsquarefeet) AS avg_calculatedfinishedsqrft,
       AVG(garagecarcnt) AS avg_garagecarcnt,
       AVG(lotsizesquarefeet) AS avg_lotsizesqft,
       AVG(roomcnt) AS avg_roomcnt
FROM lower_values;


SELECT h.avg_bathroomcnt - l.avg_bathroomcnt AS bathroomcnt_diff,
       h.avg_bedroomcnt - l.avg_bedroomcnt AS bedroomcnt_diff,
       h.avg_calculatedfinishedsqrft - l.avg_calculatedfinishedsqrft AS calculatedfinished_diff,
       h.avg_garagecarcnt - l.avg_garagecarcnt AS garagecarcnt_diff,
       h.avg_lotsizesqft - l.avg_lotsizesqft AS lotsizesqft_diff,
       h.avg_roomcnt - l.avg_roomcnt AS roomcnt_diff
from diff as h, diff2 as l;
```